# Tar files under a folder without parent folder in java

Tags: java, archive, tar

I have the following file structure under c:\Docs\Desktop

```
rootFolder
|_x1
  |_1.png
  |_2.png
|_x2
```

I have to traverse inside subfolders of rootFolder (x1, x2 ... xN) and create tar file that holds them. So x1.tar should have 1.png and 2.png

```
for(String folder: rootFolder.list()) {
    File files = new File(rootFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + folder);
    for(File subfiles : files.listFiles()) {
        fileList.add(subfiles);
    }
    generateTar(fileList,files.getAbsolutePath() + ".tar");
}
```

I am using org.apache.commons.compress.archivers inside generateTar method

```
generateTarFile(List<File> fileList, String tarName) {

    File tarFile = new File(tarName);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tarFile);

    TarArchiveOutputStream aos = (TarArchiveOutputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveOutputStream("tar", out);

    for(File file : fileList) {
        TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry(file);
        entry.setSize(file.length());
        aos.putArchiveEntry(entry);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), aos);
        aos.closeArchiveEntry();
    }

    aos.finish();
    aos.close();
    out.close();
}
```

This method creates a tar file with the same folder name (e.g. x1.tar under rootFolder), however x1.tar has the following structure

```
x1.tar
|_Docs
  |_Desktop
    |_rootFolder
      |_x1
        |_1.png
        |_2.png
```

instead of

```
x1.tar
|_1.png
|_2.png
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Well, you call `.getAbsolutePath()` on your `File` objects, that should not surprise you

Comment: but list() just returns folderName, not it's path. To access it, I have to use rootFolder.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: If you use Java 7 you could use `Path` instead; it has more facilities to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the name of the file when you are creating an entry:

```
TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry(file.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of the entry if you use the TarArchiveEntry  constructor that accepts a name in addition to the file. But that means you can't generate the tar from just a list of files: you'll need to somehow save the relative path while you walk the directory tree, or compute the relative path while you create the entries.